# How do I exit Linphone

Tags: 16.04, linphone

I have installed Linphone on Ubuntu 16.04. I found that if I close all the Linphone windows the process does not exit. I also looked through the menus and didn't find any option to quit the program.

How do I cleanly shut down Linphone on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linphone/+bug/1258654

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use the command below in the terminal:

```
sudo killall -9 linphone
```

I do not know if there are a better solution, but this works for me.